# Adding URL to IE cache from a service

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, winapi, browser-history, com-object

I have a service that needs to add URLs to the IE cache of the logged in user

In order to do that I first obtain the user's token with [OpenProcessToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and call [ImpersonateLoggedOnUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612(v=vs.85).aspx)

I tried adding the URL with 2 methods

1. Using the [IUrlHistoryStg2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774948(v=vs.85).aspx) COM interface, and calling the [AddUrlAndNotify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774944(v=vs.85).aspx) method
2. Using the [CommitUrlCacheEntryW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384270%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in the following way 
   `CommitUrlCacheEntryW(urlToEnterWithPrefix, 0, ExpireTime, LastModifiedTime,       URLHISTORY_CACHE_ENTRY | NORMAL_CACHE_ENTRY, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);`

Both methods are working fine when the processes runs under the logged-in user, but fail when it runs under LocalSystem

[CommitUrlCacheEntryW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384270%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) documentation stats that:

> WinINet does not support server implementations. In addition, it
>   should not be used from a service. For server implementations or
>   services use Microsoft Windows HTTP Services (WinHTTP).

But I could not find any method in [WinHTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384257(v=vs.85).aspx) that corresponds to [CommitUrlCacheEntryW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384270%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

I would like help with the following issues:

1. Can I use the [IUrlHistoryStg2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774948(v=vs.85).aspx) from a service to access the logged-in user's url-history?
2. How can I use [CommitUrlCacheEntryW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384270%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or a slimier function from a service to access the logged-in user's url-history?
3. Is there a third option that I still did not use?

Comment: 3) A desktop application that runs at user logon that your service then communicates with.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK., I am trying to avoid from adding an additional application\process at this point. Do you know if this can be done with only the service?

Comment: Well the Commit method is out as the docs tell you not to do it, what happens when you use the interface method from the service?

Comment: When running as a service, both:
* AddUrlAndNotify
* CommitUrlCacheEntryW 
produces the Error: `This function is not supported on this system`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reversing the  CommitUrlCacheEntryW API I found that it check

- If the current thread was impersonating
- If the processes a Service

In case either of the checks is true, it exists with error code 0x80070078

So, what I wanted to achieve is not possible from a service